# How to use double substitution in awk?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

To print the fields at 29th column in two files I used

```
paste <(awk -F, '{print $29}' PreRefFile.csv) <(awk -F, '{print $29}' Txlog.csv)
```

This worked fine.
To print all the fields starting from 29 to 189. I wrote a script as follows

```
 y=29
 while [ $y -le 189 ]
 do
   x="\$$y"
   paste <(awk -F, '{print "'"$x"'"}' PreRefFile.csv) <(awk -F, '{print "'"$x"'"}' Txlog.csv)
   y=`expr $y + 1`
 done
```

Here the value of x is replaced by "$" followed by number (First round of substitution) and it is printing "$" follwed by that number instead of printing the field at that location. How to get that field in this way.
I cannot write the same line for so many times. Suggest a method to proceed.

Also suggest another tool to do this, other than awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All what you need is the power of `awk` and a *`for` Statement*:

```
paste <(awk -F, '{ for (i=29;i<=188; i++) print $i }' PreRefFile.csv) <(awk -F, '{ for (i= 29;i<= 188;i++) print $i }' Txlog.csv)
```

**My test case:**

```
paste <(awk -F, '{ for (i=2;i<=3;i++) print $i }' foo1) <(awk -F, '{ for (i=2;i<=3;i++) print $i }' foo2)
```

***File `foo1`:***

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

***File `foo2`:***

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

***Output:***

```
2   b
3   c
8   B
9   C
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable you set `x="\$$y"` is not available in the subshells `<(...)`. Thats the problem. Use `export` to make it available in subsequently executed commands, but it will anyway be expanded by the parent shell. The subshells never see the variable, but instead see the value the parent shell substituted for it. As @[EliahKagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) noticed in the comments.

Also your `awk` can be a bit simpler. See the example (I used `echo` to simulate a file with 2 fields):

```
x=2
paste <(echo "a1,a2" | awk -F, '{print $'$x'}' ) <(echo "b1,b2" | awk -F, '{print $'$x'}')
```

The output would then be:

```
a2      b2
```

Comment: Good point: subshells, +1

Comment: @chaos Have you tried your example without `export` (i.e., with just `x=2` instead of `export x=2`)? [It works that way, too.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10861225/) `$x` is expanded by the parent shell; the subshells never see the text `$x` but instead see the value the parent shell substituted for it.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for the clarification, I tested it, it works too and edited your addition to the answer.

Comment: @chaos Thanks for the edit--but this answer is still very confusing and I'm still not sure if your explanation of the problem is at all correct. Is the problem really that a shell variable is unavailable in subshells? I recommend editing further to clarity. In particular, whether or not a variable is available in a subshell is irrelevant to *the example you have given.* I don't see how it's relevant to the OP's code either--so if it is, I recommend explaining that specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
paste PreRefFile.csv Txlog.csv | while IFS=$'\t' read a b; do
  i=29
  while [[ $i -le 189 ]]; do
    printf "$(cut -d, -f$i<<<"$a")\t$(cut -d, -f$i<<<"$b")\n"
    i=$((i+1))
  done
done
```

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import csv, itertools
with open('PreRefFile.csv') as a, open('PreRefFile.csv') as b:
    for i, j in itertools.izip_longest(csv.reader(a), csv.reader(b)):
        check = 28
        while check <= 188:
            print i[check] + '\t' + j[check]
            check += 1
```